# Is it possible to test my iPhone/iPod application on iOS 3.1.3

Tags: iphone

When building I am getting this error.

The Info.plist for application at /Users/guest2/Documents/MOYMalpha/build/Debug-iphoneos/MOYMalpha.app specifies a minimum OS version of 4.0, which is too high to be installed on iPod touch

I tried to change the verison in Xcode but minimum verison it is showing for iPhone is of 3.2..so what changes I should do to run in iOS 3.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave the Basic SDK setting at 4.x.  In the Xcode project, in the Build Settings for the Target, look for the iOS Deployment Target setting.  Change that iOS Deployment Target setting to 3.1.3, build and test.  The build may or may not work if it uses any APIs above the iOS version level on your test device.